# Paypal Not Loading in PHP Tags

Tags: php, html, forms

Hey guys I have made a form that sends out an email. When you get a confirmation that it has sent I have put a paypal link button on the page as well. When I tried to wrap it around php tags I keep getting a blank white screen. I know I have done something wrong in the code but can't find it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Order Is Processing</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $star = $_POST['star'];
    $log = $_POST['log'];
    $round = $_POST['round'];
    $totalcakes = $_POST['totalcakes'];
    $totalprice = $_POST['totalprice'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Address: $address \n Phone: $phone \n Mobile: $mobile \n Email: $email \n Date: $date \n Star: $star \n Log: $log \n Round: $round \n Total Cakes: $totalcakes \n Total Price $totalprice";
    $recipient = "demondestiny@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "New Order From Christmas Cakes For Cancer Research";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo("Your order has been sent. Please <a href='http://www.christmascakesforcancerresearch.com.au/order_form.html'>click here</a> to go back and send through the money as a Direct Bank Deposit otherwise <form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method="'post' target='_top'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='business' value='test@test.com'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Christmas Cakes'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='services'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>");
echo("<table>");
echo("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Cakes'>Cakes</td></tr><tr><td><select name='os0'>");
    echo("<option value='Star'>Star $15.00 AUD</option>");
    echo("<option value='Log'>Log $25.00 AUD</option>");
    echo("<option value='Round'>Round $60.00 AUD</option>");
echo("</select> </td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select0' value='Star'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount0' value='15.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select1' value='Log'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount1' value='25.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select2' value='Round'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount2' value='60.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_index' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>");
echo("<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
</form>");
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Any chance you could help me out with what i've done wrong?

Comment: See how the colors change in your post? You misquoted something... `method="'post'` Turn on error reporting in the future. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo at "post".

```
echo("Your order has been sent. Please 
<a href=
'http://www.christmascakesforcancerresearch.com.au/order_form.html'>
click here</a> to go back and send through the money as a Direct Bank 
Deposit otherwise <form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' 
method="'post' target='_top'>");
```

See above: **method="'post'**

Comment: New it was going to be easy lol thanks mate

Comment: @EndôFujimoto in the future use error reporting and/or an editor with syntax highlighting.